# How to compare most common words in on text file to other text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have two text files. From textfile1, I selected 50 most common words. Now I want to search these 50 most common words.

```
readFile = open('textfile1.text', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read()
words = re.findall('\w+', sepFile)
for word in [words]:
word_long = [w for w in word if len(w) > 3]
word_count = Counter(word_long).most_common(50)
count = word_count
list1=count

readFile1 = open('textfile2.txt', 'r')
sepFile1 = readFile1.read()
word2 = re.findall('\w+', sepFile1)
for word in [word2]:
word_long1 = [w for w in word if len(w) > 3]
word_count1 = Counter(word_long1).most_common(50)
count2 = word_count1
list1=count2
a=words1
c=Counter(a)
for w in words:
print w, c.get(w,0)
```

Comment: You intent is unclear, provide an example of input and expected output.

Comment: I have two text files textfile1 and textfile2. From textfile1 i select 50 most common words. Now i want to compare these 50 most common words with textfile2 that either these 50 words are used in textfile2 or not if used then how much time? The above is my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be helpful to use [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). `Counter.most_common()` returns a list of tuples, which you can convert into a `dict`:

```py
file1_common_words = dict(Counter(all_words_in_file1).most_common(50))
file2_common_words = dict(Counter(all_words_in_file2).most_common(50))
```

Then, for each word in `file1_common_words`, you can look up that word in `file2_common_words` to get its count in file 2:

```py
for (word, count) in file1_common_words.items():
    try: 
        count_in_file2 = file2_common_words[word]
    except KeyError: 
        # if the word is not present file2_common_words,
        # then its count is 0.
        count_in_file2 = 0 
    print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}".format(word, count, count_in_file2))
```

This will output lines of the format:

```
<most_common_word_1>    <count_in_file1>    <count_in_file2>
<most_common_word_2>    <count_in_file1>    <count_in_file2>
...
```

Comment: i have another question now. How should i save the above data to csv file?